# Show that the support of the shape gradient $\nabla\mathcal F(\Omega)$ is contained in $\overline\Omega$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, na.numerical-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control, flows, numerical-analysis-of-pde

Let $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space, $\Theta\subseteq C^{0,\:1}(E,E)$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space and $(T^{(\theta)}_t)_{t\ge0}$ denote the $C^1$-diffeomorphism from $E$ onto $E$ with $$T^{(\theta)}_t(x):=x+\int_0^t\theta\left(T^{(\theta)}_s(x)\right)\:{\rm d}s\tag1$$ for all $(t,x)\in[0,\infty)\times E$. Moreover, let $\mathcal A\subseteq2^E$ and $\mathcal F:\mathcal A\to\mathbb R$.

> If $\Omega\in\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal F$ admits a Hadamard semiderivative (see below) at $\Omega$ with respect to $\Theta$, let $\operatorname{supp}\nabla\mathcal F(\Omega)$ denote the set of $x\in E$ such that for every open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there is a $\theta\in\Theta$ with $\operatorname{supp}\theta:=\overline(\{\theta\ne0\})\subseteq U$ and $\langle\nabla\mathcal F(\Omega),\theta\rangle_{\Theta',\:\Theta}\ne0$.
>
> **Question**: Can we show that
>
> 1. $\operatorname{supp}\nabla\mathcal F(\Omega)=\partial\Omega$; or at least
> 2. $\operatorname{supp}\nabla\mathcal F(\Omega)\subseteq\overline{\Omega}$?

---

**Definition 1**: Let $\Omega\in\mathcal A$ and $\theta\in\Theta$. $\mathcal F$ is said to **admit a Eulerian semiderivative at $\Omega$ in direction $\theta$** if $$T_t^{(\theta)}(\Omega)\in\mathcal A\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\tau)\tag2$$ for some $\tau>0$ and $$[0,\tau)\ni t\mapsto\mathcal F\left(T_t^{(\theta)}(\Omega)\right)\tag3$$ is differentiable at $0$. In that case, $${\rm d}\mathcal F(\Omega,\theta):=\lim_{t\to0+}\frac{\mathcal F\left(T_t^{(\theta)}(\Omega)\right)-\mathcal F(\Omega)}t.$$

**Definition 2**: Let $\Omega\in\mathcal A$. $\mathcal F$ is said to **admit a Hadamard semiderivative at $\Omega$ with respect to $\Theta$** if $\mathcal F$ has a Eulerian semiderivative at $\Omega$ in direction $\theta$ for all $\theta\in\Theta$ and $$\Theta\ni\theta\mapsto{\rm d}\mathcal F(\Omega;\theta)\tag4$$ is continuous and linear. In that case, $$\langle\nabla\mathcal F(\Omega),\theta\rangle_{\Theta',\:\Theta}:={\rm d}\mathcal F(\Omega;\theta)\;\;\;\text{for }\theta\in\Theta.$$

**Proposition 3**: If $\theta\in\Theta$ and $B\subseteq E$ with $\left.\theta\right|_B=0$, then $$\left.T^{(\theta)}_t\right|_B=\operatorname{id}_B\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\tag5.$$

**Proposition 4**: If $\theta\in\Theta$ and $\Omega\subseteq E$ is open or closed with $$\left.\theta\right|_{\partial\Omega}=0\tag6,$$ then $$T^{(\theta)}_t(\Omega)=\Omega\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\tag7.$$